# Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text in ggplot (using numbers or letters as points)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset <- data.frame(CustomerId = c(1,2),
                      umap_01 = c(0.0198, -0.319),
                      umap_02 = c(0.336, -0.321))
```

And I want to create a ggplot with this code:

```
p <- dataset %>%
  ggplot(aes(umap_01,umap_02)) +
  geom_point(aes(text = CustomerId), alpha = 0.5)
```

But I received this message:

```
Warning message:
Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text
```

I don't understand why if text is a valid aesthetic. Please, could you help me this code? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is is that you want to plot? `text` is not an aesthetic, but `label` is! You also need to define a `x` and `y` aesthetic

Comment: For each point I want to show the CustomerId, In this case the x aesthetic is `umap_01` and y aesthetic is `umap_02`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another option is to use shape. If you pass a column of your data into `aes`, you'd need to use either `scale_shape_identity` or `I()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
dataset <- data.frame(CustomerId = c(1,2),
                      umap_01 = c(0.0198, -0.319),
                      umap_02 = c(0.336, -0.321))
dataset %>%
  ggplot(aes(umap_01,umap_02)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = I(as.character(CustomerId))), size = 10, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Shape was a great approach! thank you @tjebo

Answer (score 2):

You can use `geom_text`. For example:

```
p <- dataset %>%
        ggplot(aes(umap_01,umap_02, label = CustomerId)) +
        geom_text(alpha = 0.5)
p
```

[image]